# Adding Gaussian noise

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a `.arff` file which contains a list of float numbers. I need to add to every number a gaussian noise, which in MATLAB would be:

```
m = m+k*randn(size(m)
```

where `m` is one of the numbers in the list and `k` is a standard deviation and has value `0.1`. What is the `C++` equivalent to `randn()`?

Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 12):

Use [`std::normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) with an appropriate generator (`std::default_random_engine` will usually work). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random for details on all of the random number generation facilities of the C++ standard library.

([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68bd7d8f49c955f7))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main() {
    // Example data
    std::vector<double> data = {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.};

    // Define random generator with Gaussian distribution
    const double mean = 0.0;
    const double stddev = 0.1;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(mean, stddev);

    // Add Gaussian noise
    for (auto& x : data) {
        x = x + dist(generator);
    }

    // Output the result, for demonstration purposes
    std::copy(begin(data), end(data), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.987803 1.89132 3.06843 3.89248 5.00333 6.07448
```

---

**Further considerations**

For decent statistical properties, you'll probably want to choose the [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) generator (or, for convenience, the `std::mt19937` predefined version), and seed it using [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device):

```
std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
```

[*Note: Seeding from `std::random_device` is a good practice to get into; if you use the current time as a seed, you can end up with the same seed value across multiple generators (e.g. when initialising several generators in a very short period of time). `std::random_device` will obtain entropy from the system, if available.*]

In order to avoid passing the generator to the distribution every time, you can do something like:

```
auto dist = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>{mean, stddev},
                      std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));
```

which you can then use as follows:

```
double val = dist();
```

[(Live example with these modifications)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ade6e6cb7b606610)

Answer (score 4):

The c++ standard now includes several distributions for random numbers.

You are looking for [std::normal_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/).

In the documentation you can also find a [code sample](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/normal_distirbution/)

```
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);

  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0);

  std::cout << "some Normal-distributed(0.0,1.0) results:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
```

The parameters given to the constructor, std::normal_distribution,  are first mean (0.0) and standard-deviation (1.0).